# Exposing boost::gregorian::date to Python using Boost.Python

Tags: boost-python, boost-date-time

I'd like to make boost::gregorian::date available to Python using Boost.Python. But how do I create a decent `__str__` function when one is not available on the Boost date class? I'd like to write it like this:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(mymodule)
{
    class_<boost::gregorian::date>("Date")
        .add_property("year", &boost::gregorian::date::year)
        .add_property("month", &boost::gregorian::date::month)
        .def("__str__", ???)
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found the answer. You can supply static functions to .def as well. Just give it `to_iso_extended_string` and it gets the object as first argument.

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(mymodule)
{
    class_<boost::gregorian::date>("Date")
        .add_property("year", &boost::gregorian::date::year)
        .add_property("month", &boost::gregorian::date::month)
        .def("__str__", &to_iso_extended_string)
    ;
}
```